# MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to close - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I have recently installed Matlab R2015a on Ubuntu 15.10, however when I open the program I consistently get this error. I have copy'd and pasted the details below. I think the fault is coming from:

```
Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f58a634c4b0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libQtCore.so.4+00550064
```

But I am not positive. I am new to Ubuntu and am wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem and knows how to fix it.

MATLAB crash file:/home/mike/matlab_crash_dump.14223-1:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Sat Apr  9 19:16:31 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x42 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.21 stable
  Host Name           : EKIM
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.2.0-35-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 22:15:45 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11702000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007f58a1e64c80  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 0000000000000001  RDX = 0000000000000000
  RSP = 00007f5945446468  RBP = 00007f58bbb14e90
  RSI = 00007f5940003b40  RDI = 00007f58a1e64c80

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000000000001
  R10 = 0000000000000001  R11 = 00007f5938000078
  R12 = 00007f58bbb0b9f0  R13 = 00000000012017a0
  R14 = 00007f58bba8fcc0  R15 = 0000000000000000

  RIP = 00007f58a634c4b0  EFL = 0000000000010202

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f58a634c4b0 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/libQtCore.so.4+00550064


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Researching a little more and installing the Matlab support files fixed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

Comment: I also confirm that this works for Matlab R2016a and Debian testing (Stretch).